# Duplicate values being created for same column value in a crosstab

Tags: oracle, webi

I am trying to create a crosstab in webi reports that should look something like this:

[image: 1]

That is there is a person 'a' occupying a room 'Room1' for a certain date 01/01/2020 and also a person 'b' occupying 'Room2' for the same date. Have a oracle table from where I am fetching the data into the report.

But instead of that it is being displayed as:

[image: 2]

Please help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Yu can use pivot table function
there is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server/15931734

Comment: Thank you for your answer but Pivot takes fixed values and i have dynamic values.

Answer (score 0):

What object represents the values of 'a' and 'b'? Let's say it is **Person**. Create a variable called **MaxPerson** defined as follows and use that in place of **Person**.

```
MaxPerson=Max([Person])
```

Does that work for you?